# MediaInfo check AudioStreams dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, audio, stream, codec, mediainfo

I am using MediaInfo.dll with Wrapper-Class to check Video-Files for Audio-Codecs.

Can someone tell me how I can check COUNT of the Audio-Streams of the File?

```
string pfad = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] verzeichnisse = Directory.GetDirectories(pfad);
        foreach (string verzeichnis in verzeichnisse)
        {
            string[] dateien = Directory.GetFiles(verzeichnis);
            foreach (string datei in dateien)
            {
                if(datei.ToLower().Contains(".mkv") || datei.ToLower().Contains(".avi") || datei.ToLower().Contains(".mp4"))
                {
                    var mediaInfo = new MediaInfo();
                    mediaInfo.Open(datei);

                    // HERE I WANT CHECK FIRST HOW MANY AUDIO-STREAMS THERE ARE
                    // ???

                    var audioStream1 = mediaInfo.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "Format");
                    var audioStream2 = mediaInfo.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 1, "Format");  
                    
                    mediaInfo.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can check COUNT of the Audio-Streams of the File?

```
mediaInfo.Count_Get(StreamKind.Audio);
```

You may check the [MediaInfo C# example](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfoLib/blob/master/Source/Example/HowToUse_Dll.cs) for more examples.

Another example (you can find it with the linked example) :

```
mediaInfo.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "Language");
```

Jérôme, developer of [MediaInfo](https://MediaArea.net/MediaInfo).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: It is possible to get the Language of a AudioStream?

Comment: Examining the example I linked to would provide the answer, anyway I edited my answer with such specific additional example.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the MediaInfo properties here https://staxrip2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mediainfo.html

A few of them don't work, I don't know if it's a bug in the C# wrapper.

In your case, you can count the video, audio and subtitle streams respectively with:

```
mediaInfo.Get(StreamKind.Video, 0, "StreamCount");
mediaInfo.Get(StreamKind.Audio, 0, "StreamCount");
mediaInfo.Get(StreamKind.Text, 0, "StreamCount");
```